# Sum column of renderDataTable in RShiny and store results in dataframe for later use

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Not sure if I am taking the right approach here but I have created a Shiny app which works as expected.
It takes data from source and presents it as a chart and also as a table when user hits execute button.

Code for reprex below. Some functionality removed for simplicity.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton("exe", "Run", 
               style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),



  mainPanel(

    DT::dataTableOutput("datatable"),

  ))


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ga_data <- eventReactive( input$exe, {

    the_date <- as.Date(c('2020-03-01','2020-03-02','2020-03-03','2020-03-04','2020-03-05' ))
    users <- c(346, 223, 167, 431, 293)
    employ.data <- data.frame(the_date, users)

  })

  output$datatable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(ga_data())
    ga_data <- ga_data()



    })



  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I actually want to do however, is take the sum of the column 'users' and store that single value (1460) in its own variable or dataframe for later use in the code (eg as the denominator for calculating a conversion rate) and have the table NOT visible to the user.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you just define it wherever you are using it later? So within a render function, for example, and pass it on. `users <- c(346, 223, 167, 431, 293); usersum = sum(users)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, we can store the sum of the column 'users' and not have the table visible. Note the use of the `<<-`, that makes sure the value is available anywhere, not just in the place it was created.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton("exe", "Run", style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),

  mainPanel(plotOutput('myplot'))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    ga_data <- eventReactive(input$exe, {

        the_date <- as.Date(c('2020-03-01', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05'))
        users <- c(346, 223, 167, 431, 293)
        employ.data <- data.frame(the_date, users)

        #Store the sum of the column 'users' in a global variable, so we can use it anywhere later
        employ.data.sum <<- sum(employ.data$users, na.rm = TRUE)
        showNotification(paste("The sum of the column 'users' has been stored and is ready to use anywhere. Its", employ.data.sum))

        employ.data

    })

    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
        req(ga_data())
        plot(employ.data)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```